# Angular + Cordova in Virtual Directory

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova

I have an Angular application set to run in a virtual directory. (`https://{url}/{virtualDirectory}`)

I am trying to wrap this application in a Cordova application that will point to the URL as the content source. (`<content src="https://{url}/{virtualDirectory}" />`)

In my index.html file, I have added the `cordova.js` script. (`<script src="cordova.js"></script>`)

My issue seems to be that the Angular Router gets in the way. When I debug the app, I see the following console error:

`caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at cordova.js:1:1)`

When I view the sources, I see the Angular app's 404 page rendered, so the Angular routing is trying to handle this path.

We are setting a `baseHref` when we build and deploy in our Docker config, because we have to use the virtual folder:

`ng build --base-href /{virtualDirectory}/ --configuration=$environment --output-path=dist`

Which renders as `<base href="/{virtualDirectory}/">` in the actual web page.

I've tried googling this and having found any suggestions on how to fix this (or at least none that have worked). Can someone help point me in the correct direction? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue while publishing on a Virtual Directory on Apache server. What I followed are as follow:

1. Make sure your physical path folder and virtual directory folder, both should be identical. Like:

- Physical path: `D:\some-path\project-name\audience`
- Virtual path: `https://your-web-name/audience/d63b643da9b9cfc65e7d304b0aa33c98`

> In my case `"audience"` is the actual folder in which I placed all dist content.

2. Run this command `ng build --base-href ./ --deploy-url ./` (**Note**: this command will only work if you follow point 1 correctly)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this, but it's not quite working for me. When I serve locally, I can access `cordova.js`, but once I tried deploying it, I'm still getting a 404 response when trying to access `cordova.js`. This seems to have me closer to what I need, though.

Comment: In my case, I also got 404 while accessing js and assets files. Then I made my end folders unique and ran the ng build command which solved my problem. Hope so you also have a similar issue, somewhere you need to make your end folders unique.